# Six rebus puzzles - starting with three R's

Tags: rebus

More rebus puzzles:

1. RRRFOURRRR
2. Clean X
3. MMMM
4. bus again
5. Puzzle5:[image: Rebus 5]
6. Puzzle6:[image: Rebus 6]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. RRRFOURRRR

   > 4 in R's = foreigners
2. Clean X

   > Kleenex (tissues)
3. MMMM

   > 4 M's = forums
4. bus again

   > re-bus = rebus
5. dnuorg in red font

   > red ground (backwards) = red background (thanks to @Josh)
6. StateStateStateState in large black font

   > states joined together = United States

Comment: Congratz! All the answers are right!

Answer (score 4):

Puzzle 5 is actually:

> Red background

Len's got the other four right, I think. I can't make out puzzle 6.

Comment: You are Correct!

Answer (score 1):

2

> Opposite(X) of Clean, "Dirty" OR "Dirty 9" which is game Or "Dirty Dozen" which is a movie

6

> The **Four Corners Monument** marks the quadripoint in the Southwestern United States where the states of Arizona, Colorado, New Mexico, and Utah meet. It is the only point in the United States shared by four states, leading to this area's being called the Four Corners region

Comment: Sorry, but both of them isn't what I have in mind... But you have the answer of the 6th puzzle hidden in your answer...